# mv files with | xargs

Tags: command-line, mv

I'm just trying to move a bunch of files (not symlinks) out of my /etc/apache/sites-enabled folder into the /etc/apache/sites-available folder with the following:

```
/etc/apache2/sites-enabled$ find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | xargs mv {} ../sites-available/
```

but I'm an ubuntu n00b and am getting this error:

```
mv: target `./real-file' is not a directory
```

where 'real-file' is a test file I've set up on my dev environment. I'm trying to tidy up someone else's mess on a production server ;-)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You could try the `-exec` option with `find` command,

```
/etc/apache2/sites-enabled$ sudo find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec mv {} /etc/apache2/sites-available \;
```

For moving files owned by root, you need `sudo` permissions.

If you want to use `xargs` command then add `-I` option to it.

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | sudo xargs -I {} mv {} /etc/apache2/sites-available/
```

Answer (score 14):

Ideally you should use -print0 with find, so filenames with spaces don't screw things up.

E.g. this should work :

```
find . -whatever-flags-go-here -print0 | xargs -r0 mv -t target-directory
```

`mv -t` is directly usable with `xargs` as the source files are at the end of the argument list:

```
   mv [OPTION]... -t DIRECTORY SOURCE...

   -t, --target-directory=DIRECTORY
          move all SOURCE arguments into DIRECTORY
```

Answer (score 2):

you can also use another way to perform the same but with an **extra performance**:

`find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec mv -t /etc/apache2/sites-available {} \+`

Note that it ends with `\+` which means for the find command to get the output and expand into `{}` doing what you want, in this way you avoid the two options (`\;` = for each entry AND piping into a new command `xargs`)

Here is the explanation (you can also check the manual `man find`)

> **-exec command {} +**
>                 This variant of the -exec action runs the specified command on the selected files, but the  command
>                 line  is  built by appending each selected file name at the end; **the total number of invocations of
>                 the command will be much less than the number of matched files.  The command line is built in  much
>                 the  same way that xargs builds its command lines.**  Only one instance of ‘{}’ is allowed within the
>                 command.  The command is executed in the starting directory.

Comment: `+` appends the filenames at the end of the command, this would only work if you use `mv -t`

Comment: yeah. definetily forgot to add the flag. good catch

Comment: So why don't you edit the post?

Answer (score 0):

For me, my version of `mv` didn't had `-t` option and my version of `xargs` didn't had `-I` option. I couldn't even use `-exec` in `find` as first I had to filter those results. So this is what I used:

```
for f in $(find -type f | grep 'key')
do
mv $f dest/
done
```